# What does the 'X' mark on my US arrival form mean?

Tags: usa

How do I get rid of the 'X' mark on my US arrival form while returning back to the United States?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  What form are you talking about - is it 6059B? Where is the X mark, who put it there, and why do you think you need to get rid of it?

Comment: The X might be on the receipt from an APC machine or a GE machine. These aren't strictly "customs" forms, though.

Answer (score 4):

The X mark indicates that you need to speak to officials for any number of reasons. It could be as simple as the fact that you've declared food or excess items subject to duty, or a past adverse history with the US government, or even a case of mistaken identity. You might get something resembling a straight answer if you ask why you were stopped.

If you're routinely singled out for scrutiny and there's no particular reason why, you can apply through the [DHS TRIP](https://www.dhs.gov/dhs-trip) program. This is a program intended to provide redress to people who are frequently stopped or appear on watch lists by mistake, and they may be able to help prevent this from happening in the future.